# Why is the json code wrong?

Tags: json, xml

Why is the json code wrong? I know I can have multi key in XML, but it seem that json doesn't allow.

```
  {
      "BackupSettings": {
        "Setting":
          {
            "id": "34345"        
          },

          "Setting": {
            "id": "16454"
          }  
      }
    }
```

Comment: I believe `"Setting"` should be in an array. `"BackupSettings": {[
        "Setting":
          {
            "id": "34345"        
          },

          "Setting": {
            "id": "16454"
          }]  
      }`

Comment: You can’t have duplicate keys.

Comment: While XML is a notation to describe data, JSON is a notation to describe objects. In a programming language, when a variable/property is given a value twice the language designers have two choices: disallow the second value (and maybe generate an error) or let the second value overwrite the first. Remember, JSON describes an object, or more precisely JSON describes AN INSTANCE OF A CLASS. XML describes a document.

Comment: Downvoting because this question shows the OP has not even bothered to look up the syntax of JSON, nor used any of the plenty free online syntax checkers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, keys within an object are required to be unique in JSON. The canonical way of expressing your data in JSON would be to use an array. It could look something like the following:

```
{
  "BackupSettings": {
    "Settings": [
      {
        "id": "34345"        
      },
      {
        "id": "16454"
      }  
    ]
  }
}
```

Or even:

```
{
  "BackupSettings": [
    {
      "id": "34345"        
    },
    {
      "id": "16454"
    }  
  ]
}
```